# Pass variable from JSP to javascript file

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsp

I have an int variable in that gets passed into a jsp file from a java class. I now want to pass this int value from the jsp to a javascript file I have. I am stuck with a coming up with a solution. I have tried the following but still does not work:

javascript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('div.awsmp-hero-featureSwap').each(function() {
        jQuery(this).find('div.hero-featureSwap').each(function() {
            var width = 0;
            var height = 0;
            var count = 1;
            var perpage = "${products_per_page}"; //  ***** this is the value I want from the jsp*****
            var totalcarousel = jQuery('.hero').length;
            jQuery(this).find('div').each(function() {
                width += jQuery(this).width();
                count = count + 1;
                if (jQuery(this).height() > height) {
                    height = jQuery(this).height();
                }
            });

            jQuery(this).width(((width / count) * perpage + 1) + (perpage * 12) + 60 + 'px');
            jQuery(this).height(height + 'px');
        });
    });
```

JSP:

```
    <c:set var="products_per_page" value="3" />
    <c:if test="${not null model.listSize}">
        <c:set var="products_per_page" value="${model.listSize}" />
    </c:if>
```

I just want to pass the the "products_per_page" value to the javascript. should be very simple...

Comment: Is that Javascript file/snippet being parsed by the JSP engine? You might check the source and make sure the value is actually being set.

Comment: If the javascript file is external (not embedded in the page) then it won't be parsed by the JSP engine. At the same time, if the variable isn't defined, it won't be inserted even if it is embedded in the page.

Answer (score 4):

you can put your `<c:set>` block into an HTML element as its value then get the value easily using Javascript or jQuery

example :

```
<input id="ppp" type="text" value="<c:set var='products_per_page' value='3' />"/>
```

js:

```
 var products_per_page = document.getElementById("ppp").value;
```

Comment: is there any way around using a placeholder such as the input that you have?

Comment: Put a text input element on the page simply to access a value from Java? That seems a bit much.

Comment: i had in my mind that he would also want to display his `<c:set>` block. so my solution came out to this. you can always provide a better answer if have one in mind though.

Comment: @user3777012 is your `<c:set>` block need not to be shown on your jsp page?

Comment: The OP wants to use the `products_per_page` value in a Javascript snippet by putting that value into the Javascript's variable. My thoughts are the way the JSP variable is being called is incorrect, or the file isn't being parsed (correctly?) by JSP, or the assignment is happening after the script is outputted. I don't know JSP well enough to provide an answer, but seeing the OP's comment, using an `input` within the page is not the way he/she would prefer to go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, is not very recommendable.... but works..
Hard-coding the value into the html file like this:

```
<body> 
.....  
var x = <%= some_value  %>; 
.....  
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I passed the request argument to my onclick handler in js the following way:

```
<s:submit name="kurierButton" onclick="openKurierWindow('%{#attr.OUTBOUND_KURIER_URL}');" value="%{#attr.OUTBOUND_KURIER}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it this way->

servlet_file.java

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();
session.setAttribute("idList", idList);
```

.jsp file

```
<%
HttpSession session1 = request.getSession();
ArrayList<Integer> idList = (ArrayList<Integer>) session1.getAttribute("idList");
%>
```

.js file

```
alert("${idList}");
```